# Replace SQL Server 2005 cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor

Here is the simplified cursor:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

SET @curTemp = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT gpno, ssn FROM EligCov Group BY gpno, ssn
OPEN @curTemp

-- loop through cursor and build output report table
FETCH NEXT FROM @curTemp INTO @gpno, @ssn
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @trnCnt = @trnCnt + 1

    -- get the max CovEndDate for this group/ssn combo
    SELECT @MaxCovEndDate=MAX(CovEndDate) FROM Payroll WHERE GroupNo=@gpno AND SSN=@ssn
    UPDATE EligCov SET CovEndDate = @MaxCovEndDate WHERE gpno=@gpno AND ssn=@ssn

    -- check transaction counts and commit if needed
    IF @trnCnt % 2000 = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT
        END
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM @curTemp INTO @gpno, @ssn
END
CLOSE @curTemp
DEALLOCATE @curTemp 

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

Basically table `EligCov` has one distinct `groupNo/SSN` combo. Table `Payroll` will have many `groupno/ssn` combinations. Each row in the `Payroll` table has a `CovEndDate` column containing a date.

I need to just select the `max(CovEndDate)` for a certain `gpno/ssn` combination (this could be from one row or hundreds) from `Payroll` and update the `CovEndDate` in the `EligCov` table (always one row for a specific `groupno/ssn` combo).

The `payroll` table has 10,000,000+ rows and the `EligCov` table has ~200,000 rows. Is there a way to change this to not use a cursor?

To restate, for each `group/ssn` in `EligCov` look through all the records in `Payroll` with the same `group/ssn` and grab the `max(CovEndDate)` and update the `CovEndDate` in the `EligCov` table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sure - pretty easy - use a CTE (Common Table Expression) that partitions your data by the "grouping" set.

```
;WITH DataToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT  
        GroupNo, SSN, CovEndDate AS 'MaxCovEndDate',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupNo,SSN ORDER BY CovEndDate DESC) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM dbo.Payroll 
UPDATE 
)
UPDATE dbo.EligCov 
SET CovEndDate = d.MaxCovEndDate 
FROM DataToUpdate d
WHERE gpno = d.GroupNo 
  AND ssn = d.SSN 
  AND d.RowNum = 1   -- select the latest date - the one with RowNum = 1
```

The CTE partitions your data by `GroupNo,SSN` - so each group of `GroupNo,SSN` is handed out new `ROW_NUMBER()`, starting at 1. Since the rows are sorted by `CovEndDate DESC`, the latest/most recent `CovEndDate` gets `RowNum = 1`.

Based on that CTE, you then update the `EligCov` table, only taking those most recent entries, for each group of `GroupNo,SSN`

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with the CTE's and see what I get.  The cursor that I am using now is just to slow.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method:

```
UPDATE
    EC
SET
    CovEndDate = SQ.CovEndDate
FROM
    EligCov EC
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT gpno, ssn, MAX(CovEndDate) AS max_dt
        FROM Payroll
        GROUP BY gpno, ssn) SQ ON
    SQ.gpno = EC.gpno AND
    SQ.ssn = EC.ssn
```

More importantly though, I'd ask if it's really necessary to have that column in EligCov, which is against rules of normalization for a relational database.

Comment: It could be a conscious de-normalization to reduce the effort to determine the last "EndDate" ...

Comment: I know it could be. It's my experience that a lot of developers prematurely "optimize" like that though. I'm not saying that I definitely wouldn't do it, just that I'd make sure that I consciously questioned it and made sure that it was the best way to handle the situation.

Comment: The de-normalization is because this is a query to go against a payroll table and an error table, find the record between the two tables that has the latest CovEndDate and use that record to insert in to a different table on a different DB server used for reporting only.  The reporting DB cannot talk to this production DB.  Thanks for all the answers.  I will give both a shot.